# LESS and CSS range syntax for @media queries

Tags: angular, less

I am trying to experiment with the range syntax for @Media queries. But I am getting an error on compile that I can not resolve. I am doing this using an Angular framework and VS code. At this point the only thing in the project is a boilerplate HTML file and a LESS file with a single class.

The error:

```
@media screen and (width > 100px) {
                       ^
Missing closing ')'
```

The LESS file:

```
@media screen and (width > 100px) {
 .test {width: 100px;}
}
```

Version Information:
Angular CLI: 16.0.6
Node: 16.17.0
Package Manager: npm 8.19.2
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 16.2.0
LESS: 4.2.0

I'm at a loss on what is causing this error and not having any luck with searching Google. I even tried AI.

Suggestions and guesses are welcome.

I was expecting the syntax to run without errors. This is a really simplistic code, there is not much to change.

Answer (score -1):

After a great deal of trial and error. It turns out that an override is needed in the package.json file.

add this to the end of the package.json:

```
"overrides": {
  "less": "^4.2.0"
}
```

Followed by a

```
npm install
```